# run scala test from Intellij

Tags: scala, intellij-idea

Below is the main class :

```
object HelloWorld {
  def hello() = "Hello "
}
```

Below is test suite:

```
import org.scalatest.{Matchers, FunSuite}

class HelloWorldTest extends FunSuite with Matchers {

  test("Say Hi!") {
    HelloWorld.hello() should be ("Hello, World!")
  }
}
```

I wanted to run the test cases from Intellij. I tried configuration type ScalaTest and Application and the configuration package does not appear to select.

How to run the test cases from Intellij

Comment: is it a maven or an SBT application?

Comment: Just a minor point: in _Scala_, there is a convention that functions taking no arguments are declared (and called) with empty parentheses only if they mutate shared state; in your case, your function does not modify shared state, and so should be declared without empty parentheses, as `def hello = "Hello "`. Similarly, it should be called as `HelloWorld.hello`.

Comment: If its a SBT application try sbt test(to run all tests) sbt testOnly fullClassPath(to run only a class)

Comment: Thanks Mike...for explaining the concept behind mutable shared state.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I got you right but you can do it in multiple ways:

1. Right click on HelloWorldTest and choose Run
2. Right click on the file name on the project file tree and click Run
3. You can select Run in toolbar => Edit Configurations => + on left up side => ScalaTest => give it a name and write HelloWorldTest in "Test class:" => Ok and then Run and run again and choose the name you gave it

Comment: Thanks Liza. I had tried all these options and finally found that the module didn't have all the necessary libraries to run. It kept on saying main class not found...